# Problems with login screen (GDM3) on Ubuntu 20.04, nvidia card and hires monitor

Tags: gnome, gnome-classic, 4k-monitor

After migration to ubuntu 20.04 i'm facing a problem with login screen or whatever. I have nvidia 2070 card and 4k monitor. I installed proprietary nvidia (tried both) driver over "Additional drivers". I have setup scaling 2x. All things are working perfectly but if I do logout and then switch monitor off and then back on, then the login screen seems to be scaled twice, only uper left quadrant ist shown and login form for password input is shown partially in botton right corner.

If I enter my password and press enter, then the login dialog is disappearing, but only wallpapper is shown. Applications do not appear again. I can with alt-tab switch applications, but these remain hidden. With alt-f1 I can summount the app menu and start applications, but these are do not appear on the screen.

Only restart of gdm3 service (ctrl-alt-f3 to call console and then /etc/init.d/gdm3 restart)  can help to restore normal resolution/scale of desktop, but all apps are gone.

Opensource driver cannot handle 4k resolution, therefore is not useful.

Does someone any suggestions. Otherwise I have to rollback to 18.04, if it possible at all.

Comment: I had the similar issue. I switched to lightdm from gdm3 and now it's stable.
Try switching to lightdm.